# get first and second element with fopen PHP

Tags: php

I want to use 'fopen' for opening a file and finding a value that is repeated twice in one html file with other functions.

For example , in this page :

```
<h1> test </h1>
<h1> test </h1>
```

If i want to get h1 element, i can just get the first one. And the secound one is not accessable . Now , how can we access first and second and maybe next elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not accessible"? How _do_ you try to "find" these elements? You have to share your code! How else should be help you? You want us to _guess_ that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `file_get_contents()` of that file , get those HTML content and pass it to the DOM's `loadHTML()` and you can finally cycle it up using a loop as shown in the code.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h1') as $htag) {
        echo $htag->nodeValue;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/135752)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php
with this parser, you can "read" and edit html elements. It's built into php so you dont have to download or install anything